# Trying to switch a button from off to on and back again what might be the problem...?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, events, dom-events

So I was trying to make a button that upon clicking on it changes its style and upon clicking it again changes its style to the original one. I am very exhausted and my brain works on 10%, I feel deeply ashamed of myself for not being able to figure it out since I've already done it a couple of times. Sorry for the stupid question, I have been reading through google to see how to do it I used to do it on my own without searching for a method to do it and I know it's nothing complicated but I just don't know why my code doesn't work.............

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <button class="buttons-for-the-books" id="testerbuton">Buy</button>
         </div>
          <style>
          .buttons-for-the-books{
            border: 3px solid #191919;
            background-color: white;
            height:42px;
          }
      </style>
      <script>
              var valueto = "off";
      let testerbutona = document.getElementById("testerbuton");
              testerbutona.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if(valueto === "off"){
              testerbutona.style.backgroundColor ="black";
              testerbutona.style.border ="3px solid white";
              testerbutona.style.color ="white";
              valueto = "on";
              }
                if(valueto === "on"){
                   testerbutona.style.bacgroundColor ="white"; 
                  testerbutona.style.border ="3px solid black";
                   testerbutona.style.color ="black";
                    valueto = "off";                                  
                        }
            })
      
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .center > button {
      display : block;
      margin  : 1em auto; 
      }
    button.buttons-for-the-books {
      border           : 3px solid lightgrey;
      color            : black;
      background-color : white;
      height           : 42px;
      }
    button.buttons-for-the-books.reverse {
      color            : white;
      background-color : black;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <button class="buttons-for-the-books" id="testerbuton">Buy</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    const testerbutona = document.getElementById("testerbuton")

    testerbutona.addEventListener('click', function() {
      testerbutona.classList.toggle('reverse')
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes here.

1. You have misspelt `background` as `bacground` in the second if statement.
2. You need to use an `else if` statement, otherwise it will always detect the second if statement as being correct because the first one sets it to "on".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <button class="buttons-for-the-books" id="testerbuton">Buy</button>
         </div>
          <style>
          .buttons-for-the-books{
            border: 3px solid #191919;
            background-color: white;
            height:42px;
          }
      </style>
      <script>
              var valueto = "off";
      let testerbutona = document.getElementById("testerbuton");
              testerbutona.addEventListener('click',function(){
              if(valueto === "off"){
              testerbutona.style.backgroundColor ="black";
              testerbutona.style.border ="3px solid white";
              testerbutona.style.color ="white";
              valueto = "on";
              }
              else if(valueto === "on"){
                   testerbutona.style.backgroundColor ="white"; 
                  testerbutona.style.border ="3px solid black";
                   testerbutona.style.color ="black";
                    valueto = "off";                                  
                        }
            })
      
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much with that out of the way I can finally go to sleep! You saved my life!